# apache not working with index on RewriteEngine on Mac Lion

Tags: macos, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem that only happen on My mac(I do not try in another mac, but did tried on a linux and it works)

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?key=$1
```

on my index.php I put:

```
echo $_GET['url'];
```

it is return a empty array if my url is like this:

localhost/test/index/xpto

but it is return 'index2/xpto' if I put this in the url:

localhost/test/index2/xpto

So the problem is with the string index.

Do you guys know why it do not work on my mac but it does on linux?

I am using standard apache on mac os x lion.
I just change this lines on httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
....
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    AllowOverride All
    ...

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

**Edited**

By working I mean the $_GET['key'] is not empty. And shows the url I put in the browser.

but when I use this url on browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/index/xpto
```

my $_GET['key'] is empty

and if I use this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/anythingbutindex/xpto
```

the $_GET['key'] have the text:
    anythingbutindex/xpto

I did install XAMPP on my mac and this code works fine with index.
So the problem is with the default apache on my MAC.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how this is working on Linux, or what result that is "working". To me it looks like it's doing what one could expect. I however think your `RewriteRule` might be a bit wrong. What it will do is that it will pass the entire `URI` to the `index.php` file, while I think you just want to parameters after `index.php`?

If you enter `localhost/test/index/xpto`, and assuming your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/test` the string sent to `index.php` will be `index.php/exto`. Same thing apply to `index2/exto` since the RewriteRule does not care about if you enter `index` och `index2`.

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?key=$1
```

If you do want the `index` parameter in there you could change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(index/)(.*)$ index.php?key=$1$2
```

Hope it helps you forward.

**EDIT**

After the clarification I understand the question. Some testing later I found that the solution was pretty obvious, but I did not spot it at first. The `RewriteRule` is slightly off and if I use this it's **almost** working on my system.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Note the `/` before `index.php`. However this would always redirect to `index.php` meaning always match the `RewriteCond` statements. Changing the statement to this however worked at my system.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If you have `DirectoryIndex` set the `!-d` is kind of redundant since it will always try `<path>/index.html` or whatever you have configured.

Comment: Hi I would like all the url like it does in linux and XAMMP
as you said
the /test is the root of my site
if the user enter
    http://127.0.0.1/test/hello/world
I want the text 'hello/world'
if the user enter
    http://127.0.0.1/test/index/hi
I want the text 'index/hi'

sorry for my english

thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue right now and the easiest way to make it work was reinstalling apache via homebrew, so it works identical to the Linux I'm using on a VPS.
It took about two minutes to reinstall, reconfigure the port and I've used virutalhost.sh script to point to the ~/Sites folder